# Copy records to another index without ID collision

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to copy records from index to another. I'm using `reindex` like so:

```
POST _reindex
{
    "dest": {
        "index": "dst"
    },
    "source": {
        "index": "src",
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "name": "HEIDI"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't want to necessarily copy `_id` as well because the documents are different in fact and would prefer new `_id`s generated. One thing I would like to really avoid is to override document from source in target if IDs matched occasionally.

How to set this up with ElasticSearch 5?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. Just write a python script to get documents from source and do a fresh ingest into the destination. I have some python code already that does the same. Maybe it will help you. Here it is:

`

```
from elasticsearch import helpers
import elasticsearch

es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(
    hosts=[{'host': '<your-es-host-name>'}],
)

results = helpers.scan(
    es,
    query={"query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": "HEIDI"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }},
    scroll="20m",
    index="<your-source-index-name>",
    doc_type="<your-source-index-type>"
)

actions = []
for item in results:
    action = {
        "_index": "<your-dest-index-name>",
        "_type": "<your-dest-index-type>",
        "_source": item["_source"]
    }
    actions.append(action)

helpers.bulk(es, actions)
```

`

2. You can use the reindex API and avoid id collisions using this:

`POST _reindex
{
    "conflicts": "proceed",
    "dest": {
        "index": "dst",
        "op_type": "create"
    },
    "source": {
        "index": "src",
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "name": "HEIDI"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}`

But keep in mind that with #2, the ids that conflict with the destination index won't be reindexed.

Comment: Thanks! I knew about the first option but I really like the second approach and it is also not a solution because like you mentioned it will skip copying documents from source index if there is a document with the same `_id` in destination index. Actually, I have an idea.. Will check if that works and will let you know

Comment: Ok, added as additional answer. What do you think @viplov-patney?

Answer (score 2):

Adding another answer that uses `POST _reindex` as it might help someone in future. So, the trick is to add script which will be resetting `_id` to null. This helped me:

```
POST _reindex
{
    "source": {
        "index": "src"
    },
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._id = null"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "dst"
    }
}
```